# ActiveX control technology by Microsoft

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp-classic, applet

Is active X control server side or client side? I got this question in interview

It is supposed to be server side and just like applets in JAVA they are downloaded, this is my assumption. I am still wondering what should we suppose to say as they run on client side.

Comment: both....................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be either server side or client side.  Classic ASP is a technology which enables it to be used server side.  On the client side it works in Internet Explorer only. Whether using it client side or server side you would use either JavaScript or VBScript to talk to the Active X component